# how to replace images with user selected photos

Tags: arrays, swift

```
 var images      : [UIImage?] = [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

I have image array. I want to replace nil to image by button sender.tag

```
@IBAction func addImage(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
        configuration.selectionLimit = 1
        configuration.filter = .any(of: [.images])
        
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
        picker.delegate = self
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image: Add image buttons]

If array[index] is nil, show + image.
But array[index] is a photo, show photo

```
extension EditViewController: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    @available(iOS 14, *)
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        let itemProvider = results.first?.itemProvider
        
        if let itemProvider = itemProvider,
           itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
            itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (object, error) in
                if let image = object as? UIImage {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("image: \(image)")
                        
                        
                        print("IMAGES ARRAY : \(self.images)")
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
        } else {
            //
        }
        
    }
}
```

This code is PHPicerViewControllerDelegate (https://ikyle.me/blog/2020/phpickerviewcontroller)

Comment: use the selected index when you click add button and place image on selected index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do this with following method
assign tags to your UIButtons and on UIButton action add your image on specific index of array by managing an object

**e.g**

```
var selectedIndex or selectedTag // of your UIButton
```

on Button click update your selectedIndex value with

> self.selectedIndex = sender.tag

then in your **didFinishPicking** method update your images array with selected image on selectedIndex and update your buttons images with following way

```
images.insert(yourSelectedImage, at: selectedIndex)
self.setImagesForButtons()
```

now assign your selected image to UIButton using UIButton Outlet
e.g you have five outlets for your five buttons

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourButtonOutlet1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var yourButtonOutlet2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var yourButtonOutlet3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var yourButtonOutlet4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var yourButtonOutlet5: UIButton!



 func setImagesForButtons()
    {
        if (self.selectedIndex == 0)
        {
            if (images[selectedIndex] != nil)
            {
                
                self.yourButtonOutlet1.setImage(images[selectedIndex], for: .normal)
            }
            else
            {
                // set plus icon image to your button
            }
        }
        else if (self.selectedIndex == 1)
        {
            if (images[selectedIndex] != nil)
            {
                
                self.yourButtonOutlet2.setImage(images[selectedIndex], for: .normal)
            }
            else
            {
                // set plus icon image to your button
            }
        }
        else if (self.selectedIndex == 2)
        {
            if (images[selectedIndex] != nil)
            {
                
                self.yourButtonOutlet3.setImage(images[selectedIndex], for: .normal)
            }
            else
            {
                // set plus icon image to your button
            }
        }
        else if (self.selectedIndex == 3)
        {
            if (images[selectedIndex] != nil)
            {
                
                self.yourButtonOutlet4.setImage(images[selectedIndex], for: .normal)
            }
            else
            {
                // set plus icon image to your button
            }
        }
        else if (self.selectedIndex == 4)
        {
            if (images[selectedIndex] != nil)
            {
                
                self.yourButtonOutlet5.setImage(images[selectedIndex], for: .normal)
            }
            else
            {
                // set plus icon image to your button
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use in build Image Picker

```
extension EditProfileViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
//        localUserData.ProfileImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
        self.imgProfile.image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            let yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                self.imgProfile.image = self.localUserData.ProfileImage
            })
            let no = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: nil)
            self.showCustomAlert(alertMsg: ValidationMsg.imageUpload.rawValue, actions: [yes,no])
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: if you need custom alert function let me know

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer was given, just want to make it shorter.

The every button should have a tag, from 0 to 4.

Then you can create a property in your controller. Let it be `selectedIndex`. In the addImage you should add the line:

```
@IBAction func addImage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.selectedIndex = _sender.tag
    ....
}
```

Then in the delegate method after you got an image:

```
images[selectedIndex] = image
let buttons = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5]
let selectedButton = buttons[selectedIndex]

if (images[selectedIndex] != nil) {   
    selectedButton.setImage(images[selectedIndex], for: .normal)
}
else {
    selectedButton.setImage(imagePlus, for: .normal)
}
```